# CodeIgniter update database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I'm unable to update my data inside an input field. Below is my example.

[image]

When I put new data inside that input field and press edit,data should be updated in DB. The main problem is in `Model` so far I analyzed. I can't specify the `$this->db->where( 'id', $id);`

Each row's id should be specified.

***View file:***

```
<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records  as $row): ?>
<tr>
<?php  echo form_open('main/update') ?>
<td> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id ;?>" /></td>
<td> <input type="text" name="edit_tname" value="<?php echo $row->tname ;?>"/> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="edit_time" value="<?php echo $row->time; ?>" /</td>
<td>
<?php
$bttn = '<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default "/>';
echo anchor("main/update/$row->id", $bttn);

echo form_close();
?>
```

***Controller :***

```
public function update()
        {
             $updated_data = array(
                'tname' => $this->input->post('edit_tname'),
                'time' => $this->input->post('edit_time')
             );

            $this->model_users->updateM($updated_data);
            redirect('main');
        }
```

***Model:***

```
public function updateM($updated_data)
{
   $this->db->where('id', $this->uri->segment(3));
   $this->db->update('tasks',$updated_data); 
}
```

Comment: Where is the form close tag? And why an anchor when you already have a submit button? Also your form_open URL should pass the id.

Comment: @ArunPoudel I did close the form but forget to put it here, sorry for that. And about anchor tag, I'm new with php and mvc, found that on another tutorial. It would be really helpful if you put some detail answer on how should I write those codes you mentioned in your comment. :)

Comment: Why can't you use $this->input->post('id'), and pass it to model?

Comment: plus, are you closing these off `<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records  as $row): ?>`

Comment: @SanjayKumarNS I don't want to update the `id`, so kept it hidden.I just wanna update the `tname` and `time` field

Comment: You want the id in the model class to use in the where condition rt?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did close everything, just wrote down the important parts here. No problem with tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Controller:

```
public function update()
        {
             $updated_data = array(
                'tname' => $this->input->post('edit_tname'),
                'time' => $this->input->post('edit_time')
             );

            $this->model_users->updateM($updated_data, $this->input->post('id'));
            redirect('main');
        }
```

Model:

```
public function updateM($updated_data, $id)
{
   $this->db->where('id', $id);
   $this->db->update('tasks',$updated_data); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot broooo, Worked like a charm ! Thanks a lottt

Answer (score 1):

You view file should look something like this:

```
<?php if(isset($records)) : foreach($records  as $row): ?>
<tr>
    <?php  echo form_open('main/update/' . $row->id) ?>
    <td> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row->id ;?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="edit_tname" value="<?php echo $row->tname ;?>"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="edit_time" value="<?php echo $row->time; ?>" /></td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default "/></td>
    </form>
</tr>
```

**Explanation:**

- Anchor element doesn't submit form (remove the anchor element and use the submit input to submit your form)
- If you check the URL generated by `form_open` then you will see that the previously generated URL looked like `main/update` but infact we needed to post/get the values into `main/update/XX` which the suggested change does
- Closed form tag

Answer (score 1):

Your are already passing the `id` in hidden input in your form then why are you using `$this->uri->segment()` instead use `$this->input->post('id')` and why to use anchor where you are passing the `submit` button instead link your controller in `action` attribute of the form nd simply use `<input type="submit">` button directly as well as it is not good practice to not closing the `</form>` use either `</from>` or `echo from_close()` to close the form.

Since you are using `loop` which is creating multiple form and thus you are not closing the form all the multiple form is treated as single form. by closing the form at the end will solve the problem.

Hope this will help you in solving your problem